# Android:Detect what start process of your App?

Tags: android, android-broadcast

You know that process of your App may be start by other Activities(like launcher) or it may be start for special broadcast.At first and before all other elements,[Application](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC0QFjAA&url=http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html&ei=23tZUpqOMoXXtQbWjYGwCQ&usg=AFQjCNHlOiaTSPSHtnZxHDzwp7YJYgf5OA&sig2=1tt5FGjQqzaKuL3SaQKXAw&bvm=bv.53899372,d.Yms) of your App starts.You can see that docs say in about [onCreate()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html#onCreate%28%29) method of Application class:

> public void onCreate ()
>
> Called when the application is starting, before any activity, service,
>   or receiver objects (excluding content providers) have been created.
>   ...

My question is:

In [`onCreate()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html#onCreate%28%29) method of [Application](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC0QFjAA&url=http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html&ei=23tZUpqOMoXXtQbWjYGwCQ&usg=AFQjCNHlOiaTSPSHtnZxHDzwp7YJYgf5OA&sig2=1tt5FGjQqzaKuL3SaQKXAw&bvm=bv.53899372,d.Yms),is there any way to detect process of my App is started for broadcast or it is started by Activity?

Answer (score 0):

For this situation... you can create a static variable in a class and change its value in Broadcast Reciver.

Comment: Thank you,but I want to detect it before creating broadcast receiver instance.